# CSS3 animations

Tags: css3, css-animation

Нужно сделать анимацию. Хотел бы узнать: как сделать, чтобы анимация работала слева направо?

То есть: есть определённый элемент(картинка в моём случае) и нужно, чтобы она меняла свою прозрачность - слева направо(плавно), с 1 до 0(opacity), и обратно - с 0 до 1.

Comment: Слева направо что? Прозрачность — это число, число не имеет ни лева, ни права.

Comment: на нативном css? Это только через mask-image

Comment: andreymal, я думаю вы поняли о чём я имею введу - чтоб не вся картинка сразу меняла прозрачность, а с левого края и до правого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вариант но поддержка пока не очень, градиент вместо opacity

```css
body{
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/15/19/14/honeycomb-34984_1280.png);
}

.animate {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  -webkit-mask-size: 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-position: left;
  animation: opacity 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}


@keyframes opacity {
  0% {
   -webkit-mask-size: 0%;
   -webkit-mask-position: left;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-mask-size: 100%;
    -webkit-mask-position: left;
  }
  51% {
    -webkit-mask-size: 100%;
    -webkit-mask-position: right;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-mask-size: 0%;
    -webkit-mask-position: right;
  }
}

.flex{
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
<img class="animate" src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" />

<div class="animate">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: это я так понял, вы скрываете э-нты градиентом, тоесть каким-то цветом, верно?

Comment: Нет, это наложение маски на элемент, маска от 1 до 0, поменяйте цвет задника результат будет тот же.

Comment: это значит, что оно будет работать как **opacity**, то есть если за картинкой будут какие-то э-нты, они станут видны после сокрытия, да?

Comment: Да, подправил код выше, добавил патерн-подкладку, если маска не будет иметь прозрачности то и просвечиваться ничего не будет

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.window,
.curtain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.window {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  background: tomato;
  color: white;
}

.curtain {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  
  transform: translateX(-124%);
  transition: all 1.5s;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 0 30px 30px white;
}

.window:active~.curtain {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class='window'>press and hold</div>
  <div class='curtain'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: и где в Вашем примере opacity?

Comment: ничем не opacity